# Youtube embedded video (iframe) behaving weirdly in Safari only

Tags: html, iframe, safari, youtube, embed

Hello dear Stackoverflow people!
I have tried to build myself a website, there us just one thing i can't figure out and im hoping you way more experienced people could help me.

The embedded Youtube video, which is meant to serve as a background for the logo works well with FireFox and Google chrome. Just in Safari, the video skips straight to the end and the other recommended videos as soon as the page has loaded. If i open just the youtube.com/embed/ link, it works fine. Is there any way for me to resolve this?
I am not an expert concerning html5 / javascript and i have no idea why it behaves so differently in the different browsers.

I have tried to open the embed link on its own, it works when doing that.
I have also tried looking into the developer menu in safari, but there are no errors.
Sometimes, it loads wrong and if i change the tab for a few minutes and reopen the tab it gets rendered again(?) and then it works; it just never works when you load the page initially

`<iframe id="videobgframe-1936929286" class="videobgframe" style="min-height: 708.1875px; min-width: 956.4444444444443px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XzTCntGgNJU?modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;hd=1&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ajgapps.com&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=XzTCntGgNJU&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;widgetid=1"></iframe>`

The expected/desired result is the website behaving just like it does in google chrome and firefox right now, starting to autoplay the video as the logo background when the page has loaded, hiding controls, looping the video and ideally also hiding the recommended videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone wondering, I have figured it out finally.
Safari blocks all autoplaying media by default, exempting certain big websites like Youtube or Netflix.
So there is no way around this, if you want to use a video. I will try to use a different media format like a gif maybe...